# Android - Dynamic Spinner in Tab - Add Item fails

Tags: android, tabs, spinner, android-tabhost

I have a standard TabHost with a tab containing a Spinner. I am trying to populate the spinner choices with contact info. Everything seems to be working except that when the step comes to update the content of the spinner, it does not happen so the spinner stays blank all the time. I think I need help properly grabbing a handle to the Spinner adapter in a way that allows the add to occur. Here is my code:

```
    public class Page2Activity extends Activity 
implements OnClickListener, OnLongClickListener {

private RadioButton rb1;  
private RadioButton rb2;    
private RadioButton rb3;
private RadioButton rb4;

private TextView t1;
private Spinner s1;
private ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> m_adapterForSpinner;

private static final int CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT = 1001;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.tabpage2);

    rb1 = (RadioButton) this.findViewById(R.id.DE);
    rb2 = (RadioButton) this.findViewById(R.id.DL);     
    rb3 = (RadioButton) this.findViewById(R.id.DLL);
    rb4 = (RadioButton) this.findViewById(R.id.DI);     

    t1 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    s1 = (Spinner) this.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

m_adapterForSpinner = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
m_adapterForSpinner.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
s1.setAdapter(m_adapterForSpinner);

    s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() { 

        @Override 
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) { 
            String selection = s1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String[] number = selection.split(" -> ");
            number[1] = number[1].replace("-", "");
            t1.setText(number[1]);
        } 

        @Override 
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

        } 
        }); 

}
```

The above code setup the spinner and spinner selection handler which seems to work fine when I manually populate the content of the spinner in code. However, I am trying to list contact info from a Contact Picker as the items in the spinner programmatically. Here is the handler for the Picker. Everything here seems to be working to find the contact items of interest based on verification via logging but for some reason it is not actually updating the choices in the Spinner on the tab. I think it is my use of m_adapterForSpinner below that is causing the problem but I am not sure about that or how to fix it. Advice?

```
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT:
            Uri result = data.getData();
            Log.v("D", "Got a result: " + result.toString());
            Uri myURI = Uri.parse(result.toString()) ;
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver(); 
            Cursor cur = cr.query(myURI, null, null, null, null);
            if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
                while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                    String id = cur.getString(
                                cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cur.getString(
                                cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                Toast.makeText(this, name, 500).show();

                if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                    //Query phone here.  Covered next
                    if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(
                            cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                            Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", new String[]{id}, null);

                            final int contactNumberColumnIndex = pCur.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
                            final int contactTypeColumnIndex = pCur.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE);

                            while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                                // Do something with phones
                                String typename = null;
                                final String number = pCur.getString(contactNumberColumnIndex);
                                final int type = pCur.getInt(contactTypeColumnIndex);
                                switch (type) {
                                    case Phone.TYPE_ASSISTANT:
                                        typename= "Assistant";
                                        break;
                                    case Phone.TYPE_CALLBACK:
                                        typename = "Callback";
                                        break;
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        typename = "Undefined";
                                        break;
                                }
```

// Add the item to the choices in the Spinner in OnActivityResult callback

```
    m_adapterForSpinner.add(typename + " -> " + number);
                            } 
                    pCur.close();
                }}}}
            break;
        }} 
    else {
        // gracefully handle failure
        Toast.makeText(this, "Contact Selection Failed", 5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception or error? If yes then please post it here...

Comment: I would advice you to go with a simpler approach ...first declare a global(class level variable) array or arraylist whichever you like then initialize the spinner on oncreate with that(using an arrayadapter of course) afterwards when you are done retrieving the data which you would like to put into the spinner put that into the arraylist or that array you declared then update the spinner.NOTE: you have to call notifydatasetchanged() method whenever you are changing the dataset or the contents of a spinner(adapter to be specific) before actually updating it . Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Call  `m_adapterForSpinner.notifyDataSetChanged()` to updates the UI.

Or call `setNotifyOnChange(boolean notifyOnChange)` this automatically updates the UI. So you are not supposed to call `m_adapterForSpinner.notifyDataSetChanged()` explicitly.

Comment: Sometimes notifyDataSetChanged doesn't work, so you can just use yourAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true); and it will works. =)